# cv2 matching template on a black screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching

I'm trying to wait until I detect an image on a screenshot.
The problem is that when there's a fade to black, the program finds the image, which isn't black at all (see images below).

screenshot: [image: screenshot]

template: [image: template]

result: [image: result]

Here is my code:

```
def find_image_in_screenshot(template_name, *, screenshot=None, threshhold=0.99, coords=None):
    if screenshot is None: 
        if coords is None:
            coords = (None, None, None, None)
        screenshot = take_screenshot(*coords)
    
    # read bananas image template
    template = cv2.imread(f'imgs/{template_name}.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    hh, ww = template.shape[:2]

    # extract bananas base image and alpha channel and make alpha 3 channels
    base = template[:,:,0:3]
    alpha = template[:,:,3]
    alpha = cv2.merge([alpha,alpha,alpha])

    # do masked template matching and save correlation image
    correlation = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, base, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=alpha)

    # set threshold and get all matches
    loc = np.where(correlation > threshhold)
        
    cv2.imwrite('screenshot.png', screenshot)
        
    # draw matches 
    coords = []        
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        coords.append([pt[0], pt[1], pt[0]+ww, pt[1]+hh])
        cv2.rectangle(screenshot, pt, (pt[0] + ww, pt[1] + hh), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        break

    cv2.imwrite('result.png', screenshot)
    cv2.imwrite('template.png', template)

    return coords
```

I tried with different methods, different threshold, added some transparency in the image (cause I need transparency for other images), but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What does your alpha channel look like? Your template is totally opaque. It has a solid white alpha channel. That is much of your problem. You need to create a mask by thresholding the template. What is your threshold value? You should filter to keep only the largest match and then compare to threshold.

Comment: I have pretty much the same results with values like 0.9999 and 1.0. And evreytime I have between 10 and 30 matches after thresholding. I think I don't need the alpha channel on this template, and it doesn't seem to cause any problem with the other templates I use that have transparency.

Comment: If the background color is not the same in both the template and image, then you need the mask to remove the background from consideration. You should find just the top match and test that against your threshold.